# Popover / tooltip for a text in shiny app using shinybs

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

Is there a way to add popover or a tooltip to an

`output$Text <- renderText({ c("TestText") })` element, which is then rendered through `renderUI`, using shinyBS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this do?

#### Base Shiny

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  headerPanel("Tooltip test"),
  mainPanel(
    column(3,tags$div(title="Tooltip works",verbatimTextOutput("Text")))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$Text <- renderText({ c("TestText") })
  
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

#### ShinyBS

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- basicPage(
  headerPanel("Tooltip test"),
  bsTooltip("Text", "Tooltip works", placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover",
            options = NULL),
  mainPanel(
    column(3,verbatimTextOutput("Text"))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$Text <- renderText({ c("TestText") })
  
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Before posting I tried calling `bsTooltip` in `ui.R`, and it didn't work. It worked when I called it in parent `renderUI` element though. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: How come the tooltip looks much nicer (nice border and shading) in your example than when I run it (plain white box with some of the edges missing, no shadow)?

Answer (score 2):

In general you can tooltips on any Input and Output object by using their id. For example, I added a tooltip on a `downloadButton` whose id is *downloadData*, in the UI.

```
sidebarPanel(
  downloadButton("downloadData",
    label = "Save and check the Employee List"),
  bsTooltip("downloadData",
     'This is the tooltip where you can add double quotes "like this"'),
      placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover")
)
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the accepted one from Pork Chop?

Comment: PorkChop has answered your question precisely (hence my +1) related to a text box. My answer is more general since bsTooltip allows you to add a tooltip on any object (not just a text box), like a button, a slide, ..., by using the id of that object.